# OpenBSD router DNS issue?

Tags: networking, router, dns, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD box, freshly installed. Two NIC's: re0 and rl0. Internet router connected to re0. Desktop connected to rl0. But can't seem to get internet on my internal network:

```
echo "dhcp" > /etc/hostname.re0
```

I succesfully assigned 192.168.150.22 to it. Successfully pinging google.com and 8.8.8.8.

```
echo 'net.inet.ip.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo 'inet 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.255' > /etc/hostname.re0
```

IP set for on rl0 for internal network.

```
rcctl enable dhcpd
rcctl set dhcpd flags rl0
```

Enable dhcp deamon and set dhcpd flag on rl0 so clients on internal network get IP's assigned.

```
vi /etc/dhcpd.conf

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     option routers 192.168.1.1;
     option domain-name-servers 89.101.251.228 89.101.251.229;
     range 192.168.1.4 192.168.1.254;
}
```

I created a subnet, I'm not entirely sure what option routers does.
I entered two IP addressess (but there's also a domain name) I got from the /etc/resolv.conf, at line 3 behind domain-name-servers (89.101.251.228 and 89.101.251.229). I'm unsure whether or not this is correct. How to tell?

```
 vi /etc/pf.conf

 set block-policy drop
 set loginterface egress
 set skip on lo0
 match out on egress inet from !(egress:network) to any nat-to (egress:0)
 pass in on rl0 inet
```

Now the problem is that I am able to connect with my desktop onto the box from the rl0. But I have no internet. When I "troubleshoot problems" on my network, I get an error saying "Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server).

What to do? Where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it all work: I tried different DNS IP's. Now I have Internet.